# Possible explanations to a negative correlation between iron (Ferromagnetic) and magnetic field observations from orbit

Tags: planetary-science, magnetic-field

When looking at magnetic field observation of a planet with no current magnetic field, we can observe magnetic anomalies, which is basically when ferromagnetic minerals acquire remanent magnetization through a couple of varying processes. My question is if there are any suggestions or explanations to having a negative correlation between iron concentration and the magnetic field observations from orbit.
i.e As the iron concentration increases the magnetic field observations seem to be decreasing and points with a high magnetic anomalies are those with lowest iron concentration.

Comment: Can you give specific examples of this?

Comment: I've been looking at iron concentrations and magnetic observations of Mars and I noticed that there is a negative correlation between iron and remanent magnetic anomalies observed from orbit in regions with the highest magnetic field observations

Comment: @AhmedAbdulla this is a really interesting question! Do these maps say anything about the chemical form of the iron? Can you include some specific examples of a few sites that show this negative correlation? How do we know this is even true? Thanks, and *welcome to Space!*

Comment: The area of maximum Magnetic anomalies (Terra Sirenum) region seems to be showing a negative correlation with Fe concentration from GRS and Ferric NNPH and Ferric BD530 from OMEGA which I found a bit odd so was curious if there is some sort of explanation to this

Comment: Info like that should go in the question.

Comment: Some searching shows BD530 seems to be related to ferric iron oxide...a non-magnetic iron oxide that results from weathering. You'd get a strong signature wherever this material is accumulating on the surface as it gets eroded from rocks and blown around...not in the iron-rich geological formations that froze in magnetic fields as they formed. Not giving as an answer as I don't know what the others are, but this gives an example of how these might not mean what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Not all iron minerals are magnetic](https://em.geosci.xyz/content/physical_properties/magnetic_permeability/magnetic_permeability_factors.html). Their [magnetic properties vary from weak, through medium to strong](https://www.beidoou.com/materials/what-is-magnetic-minerals.html). The Curie point determines whether an allotrope of iron is magnetic. If the [Curie point is below 770 <sup>o</sup>C](https://www.thoughtco.com/not-all-iron-is-magnetic-3976017)  the allotrope will be ferromagnetic.

What you are asking about will be determined by the mix of iron minerals present at the specific location you are studying.

[Magnetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite), Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>, is a [ferrimagnetic](http://Ferrimagnetism) iron oxide and can be magnetized to be a permanent magnet.

> It is the most magnetic of all the naturally-occurring minerals on Earth.

> The relationships between magnetite and other iron oxide minerals such as ilmenite, hematite, and ulvospinel have been much studied; the reactions between these minerals and oxygen influence how and when magnetite preserves a record of the Earth's magnetic field.

Magnetite also has [the highest content of iron, at 72.4%](https://geology.com/minerals/magnetite.shtml).

[Pyrrotite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhotite) is an iron sulfide classified as a magnetic mineral. Its ...

> magnetism decreases as the iron content increases

It is a nonstoichiometric variant of FeS, the mineral known as troilite.

> The ideal FeS lattice, such as that of troilite, is non-magnetic. Magnetic properties vary with Fe content. More Fe-rich, hexagonal pyrrhotites are antiferromagnetic. However, the Fe-deficient, monoclinic Fe7S8 is ferrimagnetic. **The ferromagnetism which is widely observed in pyrrhotite is therefore attributed to the presence of relatively large concentrations of iron vacancies (up to 20%) in the crystal structure.** Vacancies lower the crystal symmetry. Therefore, monoclinic forms of pyrrhotite are in general more defect-rich than the more symmetrical hexagonal forms, and thus are more magnetic. Monoclinic pyrrhotite undergoes a magnetic transition known as the Besnus transition at 30 K that leads to a loss of magnetic remanence. The saturation magnetization of pyrrhotite is 0.12 tesla.

The nature of the ferromagnetic properties of pyrrotite are [confirmed elsewhere](https://www.minerals.net/mineral/pyrrhotite.aspx).

[Ilmenite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilmenite) is a medium magnetic mineral (paramagnetic). It is a iron-titanium oxide, FeTiO<sub>3</sub>.

[Hematite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematite) is an iron oxide, Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>, that is [antiferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiferromagnetism). Its [iron content is 70%](https://geology.com/minerals/hematite.shtml).

> Hematite is not magnetic and should not respond to a common magnet. However, many specimens of hematite contain enough magnetite that they are attracted to a common magnet. This can lead to an incorrect assumption that the specimen is magnetite or the weakly magnetic pyrrhotite.

Comment: Fantastic answer! `+1`